# SQLite slow inserts when MD5 column set as unique

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite DB with a single table for storing Apache HTTP logs.

I import the Apache log text files using a Python script which converts the time stamp to a unix-epoch integer before insert.

To prevent duplicate lines being stored, I could either create a unique constraint using all columns, or I could add an hash column to store an MD5 of the line.

So I've tried the first idea - setting all columns as unique, and that works but it does make the DB file rather large.

My preferred solution is to use an MD5 hash column. But when I do this, inserts appear to get increasingly slow.

FYI the dataset I'm testing with is a little over 8 million lines.

The **really weird** thing (weird to me anyway) is, if I create a unique constraint on unix_epoch_timestamp and md5_hash, then the inserts don't noticeably slow down.

So I've got a work-around for my problem! But I'm intrigued as to what's causing this.

I'm using SQLite 3.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 with an old Core-i5 with 4GB RAM.

With 8-millionish rows:

UNIQUE (unix_epoch_timestamp, md5_hash) ON CONFLICT FAIL takes approx. 15 minutes to import.

UNIQUE (md5_hash) ON CONFLICT FAIL takes a very long time! I've never run it to the end, but I can't see it being less than an hour.

UPDATE:
Brief summary - SQLite DB with a single table with just over 8 million rows inserted from a chronologically sorted Apache log file using a Python script. The Python script commits approximately every 10K rows.

UNIQUE constraint on epoch + md5:
Total time to insert: 13 minutes 12 seconds.
The .db file at the end is 3.3GB in size.

UNIQUE constraint on md5:
Total time to insert: 148 minutes.
The .db file at the end is 3.2GB in size.

The Python script writes out a rough percentage of the log file completed when it commits. With UNIQUE (epoch, md5) the time between each percentage increase seems constant, whereas UNIQUE (md5) the time seems to increase.

Comment: Consider how the index is sorted, and where new rows need to be stored.

Comment: I did suspect it was something to do with the unix_epoch being inserted in chronological order, whereas the MD5 is going to be pretty random, but I'm still not seeing why that should cause the inserts to be so significantly slower, or increasingly slower.

Comment: How large is the DB? I guess you see the difference between caching and swapping.

Comment: I've added a "brief summary" with DB file sizes - just over 3GB. Not sure if the slowness is a memory issue - certainly the computer does seem to lag more with the slower run, but that's a bit anecdotal! My gut feeling is that the md5-hash only UNIQUE is resulting in a skewed index somehow? For example, if I coded my own binary tree and then loaded my sorted Apache logs, then the non-randomness of the inserts would result in a skewed binary-tree. However, *I believe* SQLite uses B-trees and (1). I don't really know how they work, and (2). it still surprised me that MD5s would perform so badly.

Comment: So essentially... I'm none the wiser! Perhaps running the SQLite ANALYZE command after the inserts are complete would result in a better query plan. But does that help with inserts?